# Получение данных с помощью ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redbeanphp

Как сделать загрузку данных  через ajax?
Мне нужно, чтобы при старте html документа выполнялся ajax запрос на получения нескольких данных и записи их в соответствующие id.

AJAX запрос: (**см комментарии**)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: POST,
      url: 'php/getData.php',
      data: //что передавать здесь?
      success: function(data) { // и как правильно получить здесь?
        $("#userName").text(data[name]);
        $("#userAge").text(data[age]);
      }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Как отправить данные **$name** и **$age** из **getData.php** в ajax запрос

```
<?php
require "db.php";
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
  //Получение данных
  $name = $_SESSION['logged_user']->name;
  $age = $_SESSION['logged_user']->age;
}
else{
  header('location ../login.php');
}
?>
```

Вот на всякий случай авторизация:

```
<?php
require "db.php";

$data = $_POST;

$user = R::findOne('users', 'login = ?', array($data['login']));
if ($user) {
  if (password_verify($data['password'], $user->password)) {
    $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $user;
  }
  else {
    echo ('Неверный пароль');
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отдать json например

```
<?php
require "db.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$get_result = ['auth' => false];
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
  //Получение данных
  $name = $_SESSION['logged_user']->name;
  $age = $_SESSION['logged_user']->age;
  $get_result = ['name' => $name, 'age' => $age, 'auth' => true];
}
echo json_encode($get_result);
?>
```

И принимать соответственно

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: GET,
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'php/getData.php',
      success: function(data) { // и как правильно получить здесь?
        if (data.auth) {
          $("#userName").text(data.name);
          $("#userAge").text(data.age);
        } else {
          window.location = '/login.php';
        }
      }
    })
    return false;
});
```

Есть ещё короткий вариант записи

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('php/getData.php', function(data) {
      if (data.auth) {
        $("#userName").text(data.name);
        $("#userAge").text(data.age);
      } else {
        window.location = '/login.php';
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, сработал именно "короткий вариант записи"

Comment: @КириллМиронов думаю потому что надо было в success сделать проверку на объект и если не объект то выполнить toJSON, но это не точно=)